# iTunes on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, iphone, playonlinux, itunes

How do I install Apple iTunes on UBuntu 12.04 in order to connect my iPhone with my PC?

I tried PlayOnLinux, but it says "wine does not support usb yet" when trying to install it.

Comment: So I have to buy a Windows XP OS and install it in Virtual Drive in order to load apps on my Iphone?

Comment: Why do you use an iPhone then?